# Links in Azure Tables

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

Can someone explain what links are useful for and how they are used?

The documentation in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.addlink.aspx) is a bit sparse, and I've tried to test them but just get errors back on `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

Links are not used at all in Windows Azure Tables (that is they are not persisted).  You might be able to build up links in memory on the client, but I am not sure how useful that would be.  I think links are used for one-to-many or many-to-many relationships - so it only applies to db stuff, not tables.

Comment: Why do they exist in the TableClient then? And why doesn't they generate a NotSupportedException?

Comment: OData is not Windows Azure tables specific - it is actually used more commonly by other provider heads that do support those operations (e.g EF with SQL backend).  Each OData provider supports whatever operations they support (some less, some more).  There was an OData provider for Netflix at one point, IIRC.